# PHP Port 80 redirect + 'argv'

Tags: php, redirect

Here is the output from Live Http Headers:

```
http://www.sitename.com/loginapplet.ws?mod=main&dest=maintenance.php

GET /loginapplet.ws?mod=main&dest=maintenance.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sitename.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.sitename.com/maintenance.php?COLLCC=3673562052&
Cookie: __utma=101585024.21651761.1342192562.1342694644.1342697578.76;     __utmz=101585024.1342192562.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);     PHPSESSID=83ce1589fb215697fb3cba35531f133f; __utmc=101585024;     __utmb=101585024.2.10.1342697578
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 302 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Location: http://www.sitename.com/loginapplet.ws?COLLCC=3673562052&mod=main&        dest=maintenance.php
X-Antivirus: avast! 4
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean
```

For clarity, the problem is the addition of the `?COLLCC=` on to the query string.  I have done some googling and found other URLs that have this string appended to them but none of them were of any help.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?  My server doesn't even use Avast, and also, nothing in my application is causing this redirect internally..

The problems seems to have resolved itself.  I'm not sure why apache didn't suffer this problem like nginx did but I'm going to go ahead and guess that it's a problem with nginx that needs reviewing.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that you have Avast antivirus installed on the computer you tried this.

Comment: Could it be your computer having avast installed and checking the connection to web server, then adding the meta tags to the connection header? Just an idea.

Comment: I do, yes, but viewing the access logs everyone else attempting to access my site is getting the weird ?COLLCC added to every URL which breaks some areas of my site.  I killed nginx and started Apache on a non-standard port and the issue seems to have stopped.  This obviously isn't a solution and I'm still stumped as to what could be causing this.

Comment: Your question is about avast, but then because that was on your computer (and not your server) it is now about the COLLCC thing?

Comment: My question was about the COLLCC thing to begin with.  I'm not even using avast version 4 so these extraneous headers make no sense.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Is the question about the extra headers, OR about the `COLLCC` thing, or about both? The extra headers should have no impact and it seems that the `COLLCC` thing does. If so, we can just ignore the whole AVAST! thing.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to mention the COLLCC thing in the post, instead of drawing attention to the Avast headers. We had no way of knowing whether the COLLCC thing was intentional or not.

Comment: Also, describe the problem some more. what is happening, it seems you did some changes to apache an ngix? please change your question a bit so the problem, the expectations etc become more clear...

Comment: I would say your antivirus (on the client) is intercepting all HTTP requests (for example using proxy).